# How to plot heatmap onto mplsoccer pitch?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

Wondering how I can plot a seaborn plot onto a different matplotlib plot. Currently I have two plots (one a heatmap, the other a soccer pitch), but when I plot the heatmap onto the pitch, I get the results below. (Plotting the pitch onto the heatmap isn't pretty either.) Any ideas how to fix it?

Note: Plots don't need a colorbar and the grid structure isn't required either. Just care about the heatmap covering the entire space of the pitch. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mplsoccer import Pitch
import seaborn as sns

nmf_shot_W = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucas-nelson-uiuc/datasets/main/nmf_show_W.csv').iloc[:, 1:]
nmf_shot_ThierryHenry = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucas-nelson-uiuc/datasets/main/nmf_show_Hth.csv')['Thierry Henry']

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', line_zorder=2,
              pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#efefef')
dfdfdf = np.array(np.matmul(nmf_shot_W, nmf_shot_ThierryHenry)).reshape((24,25))
g_ax = sns.heatmap(dfdfdf)
pitch.draw(ax=g_ax)
```

Current output:

[image: messed up heatmap plot]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: What does the output look like? and I got an error when running your code

Comment: @I'mahdi sorry about that - sample code has been fixed. My output looks like the image above (should be scaled to fit entire pitch but currently does not).

Comment: The pitch coordinates range (0,0) to (120,80) - upper left to bottom right. It's getting stuck in the region (0,0) to (24,25) which has something to do with me `.reshape()` above. Just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: do you want the heatmap to show on all of your mplsoccer.Pitch?

Comment: @I'mahdi yes. The heated region in the current map should be in the right half's goal for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in [`pitch.heatmap`](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mplsoccer.pitch.html#mplsoccer.pitch.Pitch.heatmap):

[image]

[`pitch.heatmap`](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mplsoccer.pitch.html#mplsoccer.pitch.Pitch.heatmap) expects a `stats` dictionary of binned data, bin mesh, and bin centers:

> **`stats`** (dict) – The keys are `statistic` (the calculated statistic), `x_grid` and `y_grid` (the bin's edges), and `cx` and `cy` (the bin centers).

In the [mplsoccer heatmap demos](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/pitch_plots/plot_heatmap.html), they construct this `stats` object using [`pitch.bin_statistic`](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mplsoccer.pitch.html#mplsoccer.pitch.Pitch.bin_statistic) because they have raw data. However, you already have binned data ("calculated statistic"), so reconstruct the `stats` object manually by building the mesh and centers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mplsoccer import Pitch

nmf_shot_W = pd.read_csv('71878281/nmf_show_W.csv', index_col=0)
nmf_shot_ThierryHenry = pd.read_csv('71878281/nmf_show_Hth.csv')['Thierry Henry']

statistic = np.dot(nmf_shot_W, nmf_shot_ThierryHenry.to_numpy()).reshape((24, 25))

# construct stats object from binned data, bin mesh, and bin centers
y, x = statistic.shape
x_grid = np.linspace(0, 120, x + 1)
y_grid = np.linspace(0, 80, y + 1)
cx = x_grid[:-1] + 0.5 * (x_grid[1] - x_grid[0])
cy = y_grid[:-1] + 0.5 * (y_grid[1] - y_grid[0])
stats = dict(statistic=statistic, x_grid=x_grid, y_grid=y_grid, cx=cx, cy=cy)

# use pitch.draw and pitch.heatmap as per mplsoccer demo
pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', line_zorder=2, pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#efefef')
fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(6.6, 4.125))

pcm = pitch.heatmap(stats, ax=ax, cmap='plasma')
cbar = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax, shrink=0.6)
cbar.outline.set_edgecolor('#efefef')
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color='#efefef')
plt.setp(plt.getp(cbar.ax.axes, 'yticklabels'), color='#efefef')
```